# LINQ Left outer join - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, left-join

I have two queries which look like this:

```
var ret = (from x in _context.CustomUsers
            where x.Name != currentUser
            join c in _context.Claims on x.Name equals c.UserID into m
            from c in m.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new UsersClients
            {
                UserName = x.Name,
                DefaultClient = "N/A",
                Role = null
            }).ToList();
```

This returns a list like so:

```
User1   N/A   null
User2   N/A   null
User3   N/A   null
```

For this:

```
var q = (from x in _context.Claims
            where x.Default == true
            select new
            {
                x.UserID,
                x.ClientName
            }).ToList();
```

This returns a list like so:

```
User1   Client1
User2   Client3
```

The first query returns users which do not exist in the second query. I would then like to do a left outer join on both results so I can pull the client from the second query and if it's empty. Replace it with a string.

My third query looks like this:

```
var p = (from x in ret
            join o in q on x.UserName equals o.UserID into l
            from s in l.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new UsersClients
            {
                UserName = x.UserName,
                DefaultClient = (s.ClientName == null ? "God dammit work" : s.ClientName),
                Role = null
            }).ToList();
```

I know why it fails, I just don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me so the final result looks like this:

```
    User1   Client2   null
    User2   Client1  null
    User3   Work dammit   null
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to query multiple left join in C#/linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430511/unable-to-query-multiple-left-join-in-c-linq)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems `s` is already `null` if `l` is empty. So you need to check `s` for `null` too:

```
DefaultClient = (s == null || s.ClientName == null ? "God dammit work": s.ClientName),
```

or in C# 6 and with null coalescing operator:

```
DefaultClient = s?.ClientName ?? "God dammit work",
```

Comment: This returns "God dammit work" for people who actually have clients

Comment: This returns only "God dammit work" if `s` or `s.ClientName` is null. Are you sure your query is correct? Maybe the join on `UserName` to `UserID` is incorrect?

Comment: I've just checked, the join is fine and s.ClientName isn't null. This is strange. It's only doing it for one user

Comment: Apologies, the join isn't correct. I had a lower case char in one